# remember me function in splash screen?

Tags: java, android

So when I open the app, I want to start an activity (Splash screen) and show it for 5 seconds. In those 5 seconds I can check if the user checked the "Remember me" CheckBox (saved the state of the CheckBox in a SharedPreferences value) and if they did then call my server and use the previous email and password (saved in a SharedPreferences file) to sign them in and load the BuyerHomePage activity, if not then I want them to go to the SignInOrSignUp activity.

So far everything works fine but I get stuck on the splash screen forever.

**Here's my code**:

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

            RememberMe();

        }


        public void Delay(final boolean RememberMe) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (RememberMe == true) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BuyerHomePage.class));
                    } else {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInOrSignUp_Activity.class));

                    }
                    SplashScreen.this.finish();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }

        public void RememberMe() {
            SharedPreferences RememberMeState = getSharedPreferences("RememberMeState", MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean RememberMe;
            if (RememberMeState.getBoolean("Check", true)) {
                RememberMe = true;
            } else {
                RememberMe = false;
            }

            if (RememberMe == true) {
                SharedPreferences UserCredentials = getSharedPreferences("UserCredentials", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String RememberEmail = UserCredentials.getString("UserEmail", "");
                String RememberPassword = UserCredentials.getString("UserPassword", "");

                RememberMeLogIng(RememberEmail, RememberPassword);
            } else {
                Delay(RememberMe);
            }
        }


        public void RememberMeLogIng(String RememberEmail, String RememberPassword) {
            String method = "RememberLogin";
            BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
            backgroundTask.execute(method, RememberEmail, RememberPassword);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need the delay

Answer (score 1):

You should call the finish first.

```
public  void Delay(final boolean RememberMe){
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SplashScreen.this.finish();
        if(RememberMe == true) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BuyerHomePage.class));
        }else{
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInOrSignUp_Activity.class));
        }            
    }
  }, 5000);
}
```

I wrote your method like this. If this did not work, may be you should post your AsyncTask class also.

```
public void RememberMe(){
    SharedPreferences RememberMeState = getSharedPreferences("RememberMeState",MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean RememberMe = RememberMeState.getBoolean("Check", false);
    if(RememberMe){
        SharedPreferences UserCredentials = getSharedPreferences("UserCredentials",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String RememberEmail = UserCredentials.getString("UserEmail", "");
        String RememberPassword = UserCredentials.getString("UserPassword", "");

        RememberMeLogIng(RememberEmail, RememberPassword);
    }
    else{
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginACtivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: then you need to post your BackgroundTask class since the background processing does not return.

Comment: no i figured it out myself, i never called the Delay(); method in my RememberMeLogIng(); method and now everything work :) thanks for the help tho!!!